# Modelling sky type as an area light source

Tags: optics, atmospheric-science, weather

I have a trouble understanding the mapping going on [here](https://www.new-learn.info/packages/clear/visual/daylight/sun_sky/sky_types.html). The author asserts that sky types can be modelled as follow :
[image]

The first one appears to represent a clear sky view, the second is more of an intermediate view, the third should represent an overcast view while the fourth is a uniform sky.

[image]

The figure above shows what each sky type looks like in terms of altitude angle which is what I am not understanding. For instance, how can we look at the first area light source and know how its making an angle $60^{\circ}$ at a region where there's maximum luminosity as shown in the graph? where's the reference taken to measure this angle?

Comment: This is more of a game design question.

Comment: I think the chart is not plotted _from_ the sky dome images, but rather both the images and the chart were made based on some other data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you cite says:

> The sky distributions in the graph were generated with the RADIANCE synthetic imaging system. The sun was assumed to be at an altitude of 60° due South. The sky luminance was then mapped between the Southern (0°) and the Northern (180°) horizon passing through the zenith (90°).

So at the time these images were generated the Sun is 60° above the horizon:

[image: Sun]

In the graphs the angle is the angle above the southern horizon, so at an angle of 60° you are looking directly at the Sun. That's why the maximum brightness is at that angle.